# How to fix wrong contrib URL for R devel?

Tags: r, macos, package, r-devel

I've installed and I'm currently running the devel version of R for MacOS, but I've stumbled upon a strange issue when installing packages via 'install.packages'.
I've changed the default CRAN mirror to https://mac.r-project.org/, thing is the packages on this mirror are placed at this url for the devel version https://mac.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/r-devel/ while on my machine R is automatically looking for https://mac.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/ which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to specify the exact location of this folder when installing? I've googled but the only thing I found was how to change mirrors (which I already did).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my bad. I'm leaving this here in case someone needs it in the future.

When calling 'install.packages' there is an argument 'contriburl' in which you can specify the url to the folder like so:

```
install.packages('devtools', contriburl = "https://mac.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/r-devel/")
```